# AngularJS Wait for scope variable to evaluate from custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm staring my way in AngularJS.

I have created a custom directive:

```
app.directive('myScroll',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,

    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope , element , attrs) {

    element.addClass('scroll-pane');

    scope.$watch('tasks', function(newval, oldval){
          if ( newval  ) 
          {

            console.log(newval);
            console.log(newval.length);
        }

    });

        console.log("afer watch exper");
        console.log (tasks);



    }


  };
```

});

with the following HTML:

```
<div my-scroll>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="task-wrapper">
                <div class="task-element">
                    <div class="name">{{task.name}}</div>
                    <div class="text">{{task.action}}</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

the tasks object is evaluated through a service called by the controller ( if necessary i will post its code).

in the directive code the tasks object is undefined, since i have to get the tasks length to execute more css commands i have to wait for ng-repeat to finish or just wait for tasks variable will be evaluated.

for some reason tasks is always undefined both outside and inside the $watch statement. 
i can see in the console that "after the watch exper" is printed first and then the "in watch" but still no values. 
the newval object has [move2:function] but its length property keeps returning 0 but it keeps an array of resources with my tasks.

what am i missing here and how can i execute command when the tasks variable is evaluated?

thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `scope.tasks` to refer the data.

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,

        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.addClass('scroll-pane');

            scope.$watch('tasks', function (newval, oldval) {
                if (newval) {
                    console.log(newval);
                    console.log(newval.length);
                }
            });
            console.log("afer watch exper");
            console.log(scope.tasks); //this will log the actual data.
        }
    };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [{
        name: "task1",
        action: "action1"
    }]
}
```

Comment: thanks ! stupid mistake by me... i  have one more little question, i can see that the watch expression is called twice, why?? because of the asyc service call to the db?

Answer (score 5):

Try passing the 3rd parameter - **true** to $watch:

```
scope.$watch('tasks', function(newval, oldval){
    if(newval){
        console.log(newval);
        console.log(newval.length);
    }
},true);
```

Comment: This worked for me, and from the docs I see passing `true` forces comparison on object equality instead of reference. Do you know why it's needed here?

Comment: When you pass true as the 3rd parameter, angular creates a deep copy of the model that's being watched. 

Also, as the document reads : "To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. It also means that watching complex options will have adverse memory and performance implications."

So, keeping a watch on huge objects is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I got stuck on this a few times so I made a plunker to demonstrate the difference: http://plnkr.co/edit/DHJPwMOg4LZTSk1uiV9z?p=preview